# "I have not always been teaching to pupils from this age"

Tags: present-tense

A teacher that has not yet retired but is going to  soon  says

> I have been teaching for 15 years now, this year my pupils are 12 years old but **I have not always been teaching** to pupils from this age

I was wondering if present perfect continuous is a good choice or shall I use present perfect simple (i don't think so because the situation is still true and there is a chance that the situation will be  true until he retires  )or past simple (but as he is still teaching i don't think it will match

Comment: I would use "I have been teaching for 15 years now. This year my pupils are 12 years old, but I have not always taught 12-year-olds."  In your version, it is important to remove the word "from", and you should also remove the "to", but it isn't as big a deal.  Using "from this age" is usually used when stating a range of ages - "from this age up" or "from age 12 to age 20"

Comment: Why not have been teaching because I have always been teaching

Comment: why not have not always been teaching is it because it is completed so simple is better i don't understand the logic to use simple or continuous in that case

Answer (score 1):

Your original sentence was,

> `I have been teaching for 15 years now, this year my pupils are 12 years old but I have not always been teaching to pupils from this age`

The original sentence is grammatically incorrect.

Note that "`I have been teaching for 15 years now`" is a complete sentence. Get rid of the comma and replace it with a full-stop; or in American English, replace the comma with a period.

> I have been teaching for 15 years now. This year my pupils are 12 years old but I have not always been teaching to pupils from this age. (**Iteration 2**)

This is still grammatically incorrect. Insert a comma before "**but**".

> I have been teaching for 15 years now. This year my pupils are 12 years old, but I have not always been teaching to pupils ***from*** this age (**Iteration 3**)

This is still grammatically incorrect). The word "***from***" sticks out like a sore-thumb. Replace "***from***" with a conjugation of "***to be***".

> I have been teaching for 15 years now. This year my pupils are 12 years old, but I have not always been teaching to pupils who ***are*** this age. (**Iteration 4**)

Iteration 4 is more grammatically correct than the original (relatively speaking), but is still incorrect. I will temporarily get rid of the word "***but**" and form two separate sentences. We can re-insert a coordinating conjunction later. However, English is easier to analyze when broken into individual sentences where each sentence is as simple as we can make it:

> I have been teaching for 15 years now. This year my pupils are 12 years old.  I have not always been teaching to pupils who are 12 years old (**Iteration 5**)

The phrase "*been teaching to*" can be simplified to "*taught*".

> I have been teaching for 15 years now. This year my pupils are 12 years old.  I have not always ***taught*** pupils who are 12 years old. (**Iteration 6**)

Some people would choose to write "**were** 12 years old" instead of "**are** 12 years old". However, my preference would be to almost re-write the whole thing:

> I have been teaching for 15 years now. This year my pupils are 12 years old, but my pupils have not always been 12 years old. (**Iteration 7**)

Finally, this iteration (**Iteration 7**) is grammatically correct. However, it is a little stilted.

If you want a less-stilted alternative then use one of the following:

> I have been teaching for 15 years now. This year my pupils are 12 years old, but I have not always been teaching pupils who are that age. (**Alternative A**)

> I have been teaching for 15 years now. This year my pupils are 12 years old, but I have not always taught pupils who are that age. (**Alternative B**)

In American English, "***pupil***" is almost archaic. Americans would write, "**student**". However, you are either Indian or British and I would use whichever word (pupil or student) is most common in India and/or The United Kingdom.

Comment: Nice answer. Plus 1.

Comment: It is undoubtedly true that “my students have not always been twelve years old,” but that does not really say what was intended.